# Whats best practice for implementing a BST for strings of unkown length in C?

Tags: c, tree, dynamic-memory-allocation, c11

I have to build a data structure to store strings that are getting piped into my c program. Its not possible to find an upper bound for the length of the strings, so they have to get stored in a dynamic array each. I was thinking about struct hack/Flexible Array Members as nodes but i guess its not possible because the parent/child pointers cant be allocated dynamically? Is that right?
So whats the best practice for implementing a BST thats matching those requirements?

Comment: Just let each node to have a pointer to `char` which will be dynamically allocated.

Comment: Ye okay thats kind of obvious, iam just not very familiar with C. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: SomeKlausi, "Its not possible to find an upper bound for the length of the strings," well there is the implementation bounds of `SIZE_MAX`, likely a couple billion. IAC, defensive programming handles lengths of [0....some sane amount] and whines otherwise.  Research `strdup()`.